# SSH Issue on AIX 6.1

Tags: unix, aix

I recently upgraded the openssl version on AIXX 6.1 server.

The install went fine.

But now I'm unable to start new ssh sessions from puty to the server and I'm getting the error "Connection Refused".

But I have one putty terminal open which is active.

I tried the command  `startsrc -s sshd` and it returns a new pid but I'm not able to start new sessions.

I tried the following command too and it gives the foll error:

```
root:stud -> $ /usr/sbin/sshd -de
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /usr/sbin/sshd because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.0) could not be loaded.
        0509-152   Member libcrypto.so.0 is not found in archive
```

And sshd is inoperative.

```
root:stud -> $  lssrc -s sshd
Subsystem         Group            PID          Status
 sshd             ssh                           inoperative
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it worked the first time.  That is odd.  The error says you need the lib crypto library.  Is it installed?  i.e. what does

```
ls /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a
```

return?  If it exists, you want to try:

```
ar t /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a
```

and you should see libcrypto.so.0 inside.  My guess is one of those two will not be true and you need to install it.  But it might be that libcrypto.so.0 will not load for its own reasons.

Is this the official ssh package for AIX or is it something you got somewhere else?  (I just compile mine from the source from scratch but that's not easy sometimes).